# LLVM: what does #uses indicate in a callgraph

Tags: c++, llvm

So I generated the callgraph by the following code:

```
virtual bool runOnModule(Module &M) {
  
  CallGraph CG = CallGraph(M);
  CG.dump();
}
```

The output is like this (I simplified it):

```
Call graph node for function: 'function1'<<0x563f43b334e0>>  #uses=2
  CS<0x563f442ea418> calls function 'function2'
  CS<0x563f442ea888> calls function 'function3'
  CS<0x563f442eabf8> calls function 'function3'
  CS<0x563f442eb1e0> calls function 'function4'
  CS<0x563f442ebcf0> calls function 'function5'
  CS<0x563f442ebdb0> calls function 'function6'
  CS<0x563f442ec080> calls function 'function7'
  CS<0x563f442ec110> calls function 'function6'
  CS<0x563f442ecb10> calls function 'function4'
  CS<0x563f442ecbd0> calls function 'function6'
  CS<0x563f442ecde0> calls function 'function7'
  CS<0x563f442ece70> calls function 'function4'
```

I don't understand what this #uses stands for. My guess is that it stands for the number of direct calls from this node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the LLVM code

```
OS << "<<" << this << ">>  #uses=" << getNumReferences() << '\n';
```

From the manual [getNumReferences()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CallGraphNode.html#ac7d600e0d783d8c4f8980bfe9daa6ae7)

> Returns the number of other CallGraphNodes in this CallGraph that reference this node in their callee list.

It's a number of other nodes that call this node.